# iOS Twilio place audio file during a call

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio

Is it possible to play some audio files, one after the other, when the connection is already established? I'm writing the app for iOS. do outbound calls is working. the best way should be to play an audio file instead of the microphone input. the microphone will not be used for this app...

Comment: Could you be a little clearer with what you want to achieve here, please? Also what have you tried so far? Thanks

Comment: currently i'm testing this app with twilio, maybe there is a better solution. the app should call someone and when the connection is established, you can select,stream some audio files from the ios to the call receiver. the call receiver is in the cellular network...

Comment: Ah, ok, that's not something I know I'm afraid. Hopefully someone else can weigh in.